# Multiple words option

Tags: python, python-click

I'm currently trying to use multiple words options with click:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--do-not-destroy', is_flag=True, default=False, 
              help='Do not destroy Selenium containers on exit')
@click.option('--run-tests', default=True, help="Run the tests.")
def main(do-not-destroy, run-tests):
    ...
```

Typically, I want to have an option that is called 'do-not-destroy'. Since the names of the parameters of the decorated function should be the name of the option, the parameter should be called 'do-not-destroy'.

Obviously, this parameter name is not valid.

Is there a way to tell click the name of the parameter it should use for an option (e.g. do_not_destroy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click maps any options/arguments with dashes (`-`) to underscores (`_`).  So:

```
--do-not-destroy
```

becomes:

```
def main(do_not_destroy):
```

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--opt-with-dashes')
def hello(opt_with_dashes):
    """A Simple program"""
    click.echo('Opt w/ Dashes: {}'.format(opt_with_dashes))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello('--opt-with-dashes OPTION'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
Opt w/ Dashes: OPTION
```